# Returning an array from function to main sub

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'd like to store all tab names in a string array, that I'll later use for other things. My current problem is, that I'd like to populate my array in a separate function and when thats done, hand it back to my main sub.

It throws

> Can't assign to array

as an error, what am I'm not seeing here?

```
Sub Captions_Formatting()
    Dim tabName() As String
    Dim totaltabs As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim captionlines As Integer

    totaltabs = get_Tabs
    tabName = getTabNames(ws, totaltabs)

End Sub

Function getTabNames(ws As Worksheet, totaltabs As Long) As String()
Dim i As Integer
ReDim tabName(totaltabs)

    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Overview" Then
            tabName(i) = ws.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws

getTabNames = tabName

End Function
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `Function getTabNames(ws As Worksheet, totaltabs As Long) As Variant`

Comment: Your function has two arguments, which you are not populating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to type your array to match the function return type:

```
ReDim tabName(totaltabs) As String
```

If you do not then its an array of variants and such a thing cannot be cast to an array of strings automatically (or at all).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot, thats it! I wasn't aware that if I redim an array, it also needs a type, since it was initially dimmed as string()

Comment: Well the tabName in Captions_Formatting is a string but its local to that function so the tabName in getTabNames is a completely separate thing.

Comment: Ah ok, if I'd like to use the same array I probably need to pass the array by using byRef, correct?

Comment: Yes you could, although no point in this case as you return the data anyway.